# Double integration with $\log$

Tags: integration

I want to calculate double integral as follows,

$\frac{9}{2 \pi^2} \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-2}^2 t^2 s^2 \log \frac{4 - ts + \sqrt{(4 - t^2) (4 - s^2)}}{4 -ts - \sqrt{(4 - t^2)(4 - s^2)}} ds dt$.

I tried to use triangle transformation, but still could not solve the $\log$ part. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: \begin{align} \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-2}^2 t^2 s^2 \log \frac{4 - ts + \sqrt{(4 - t^2) (4 - s^2)}}{4 -ts - \sqrt{(4 - t^2)(4 - s^2)}} ds dt&=4\int_{0}^2 \int_{0}^2 t^2 s^2 \log \frac{4 - ts + \sqrt{(4 - t^2) (4 - s^2)}}{4 -ts - \sqrt{(4 - t^2)(4 - s^2)}} ds dt\\ &=256\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 t^2 s^2 \log \left(\frac{1 - ts + 4\sqrt{(1 - t^2) (1 - s^2)}}{1 -ts - 4\sqrt{(1 - t^2)(1 - s^2)}}\right) ds dt\\ \end{align}

Comment: It seems that the argument of the logarithm could be non-positive.

Comment: Thank you very much. But for the first equation, the integral function is not even function with respect to $t$ or $s$, so maybe it does not hold. And for the second equation, the number 4 are forgotten to be removed. Could this be  calculated then?

Comment: Doris: my mistake sorry.